# Combine 3 sql query in one

Tags: php, sql, join

I need a way to do only one sql query for those 3 query, i tried with join but it don't seems to work. I think there is a more simple way of doing those 3 query.

```
function get_post_version ($id,$type){

        global $bdd;

    $req= $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM term_relationships WHERE post_id = :id AND type= :type');

    $req->execute(array(        
        'id'      => $id,
        'type'    => $type

        ));

    $term_taxonomy = $req->fetch();

    $req2= $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM term_taxonomy WHERE term_taxonomy_id = :id');

    $req2->execute(array(       
        'id'      => $term_taxonomy['term_taxonomy_id'],

        ));

    $term = $req2->fetch();

    $req3= $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM terms WHERE id = :id');

    $req3->execute(array(       
        'id'      => $term['term_id'],

        ));
    $the_term = $req3->fetch();

    return $the_term;


}
```

i tried this

```
$req= $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM terms t
                        JOIN term_relationships tr WHERE post_id = :id AND type= :type
                        JOIN term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
                        WHERE t.id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
```

But it don't seems to work

Comment: Try LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN instead of JOIN

Comment: ok i used a software called Razor sql to build the query, this is it :

SELECT
    terms.name
FROM
    streaming.terms terms,
    streaming.term_taxonomy term_taxonomy,
    streaming.term_relationships term_relationships
WHERE
    terms.id = term_taxonomy.term_id AND
    term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id AND
    term_relationships.post_id = :id AND
    term_relationships.type = :type
It's working perfectly.